# How do I get fitted lines in each plot of a scatterplot matrix in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, scatter-plot

I know how to use the 'abline' function with a single plot but how do I get a scatterplot matrix which will also show the fitted lines in each plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the car package you can use the 'scatterplotMatrix' function.

Here's an example using the Prestige dataset in that package:
library(car)
scatterplotMatrix(~prestige +income +education + women, data= Prestige)